# Cython setting external variable causes access violation

Tags: python, dll, cython

I'm trying to use cython to wrap an external library.  Part of the interface to the external library requires me to set a member of an external variable that is exported from a dll, but I'm getting an Access Violation error:

> Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

I'm using Cython with Python 2.7 and the compiler suite from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266 .  Everything is compiling and linking properly using setuptools.

The following .pyx code contains the problem:

```py
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as cnp

ctypedef float real32_T

ctypedef struct ExtU_ST_TopLevel_MWL_T:
    real32_T GroundSpeed

cdef extern from 'ST_TopLevel_MWL.h':

    void ST_TopLevel_MWL_initialize()
    void ST_TopLevel_MWL_step()
    void ST_TopLevel_MWL_terminate()

    ExtU_ST_TopLevel_MWL_T ST_TopLevel_MWL_U


def ST_TopLevel_MWL_batch_run(cnp.ndarray[cnp.double_t, ndim=1, mode='c'] ground_speed not None):
    global ST_TopLevel_MWL_U
    ST_TopLevel_MWL_initialize()
    print('0x%x' % <unsigned long long>&ST_TopLevel_MWL_U)
    print('0x%x' % <unsigned long long>&ST_TopLevel_MWL_U.GroundSpeed)
    print('%f' % ST_TopLevel_MWL_U.GroundSpeed)
    # The following line results in the access violation
    ST_TopLevel_MWL_U.GroundSpeed = <float>0.0
    print('%f' % ST_TopLevel_MWL_U.GroundSpeed)
    ST_TopLevel_MWL_terminate()
```

The `ST_TopLevel_MWL_U.GroundSpeed = <float>0.0` line results in the access violation.  If I remove that line, I don't get an access violation, but, of course, I can't use the dll if I can't set this variable.

I believe that setuptools is statically linking a library (.lib) that is responsible for dynamically loading the dll (.dll), but the mechanics of that are totally hidden from me, so I'm having trouble find the root cause.

The dll that I'm trying to interface with is generated and built from Matlab Simulink embedded coder using the 'ert_shrlib.tlc' target with the 'Microsoft Windows SDK v7.1 | nmake (64-bit Windows)' toolchain.

Comment: Removed the MATLAB tag.  This has to do with Python / Cython, not MATLAB.

Comment: I included it because the dll that I'm trying to interface with is generated and built from Matlab Simulink embedded coder using the 'ert_shrlib.tlc' target with the 'Microsoft Windows SDK v7.1 | nmake (64-bit Windows)' toolchain.

Comment: That wasn't in your question.  In fact, I searched your entire question for anything related to MATLAB and it wasn't visible....so I removed the tag.  In any case, the fact that the DLL came from MATLAB (to me) seems irrelevant.  As such, please either edit your question to reflect this information, or leave the MATLAB tag out of your question.

Comment: True, I trust that the source of the dll doesn't have any impact on my specific problem, unless the toolchain used to generate the dll (SDK v7.1) is not compatible with the toolchain used to build cython (VC 9.0), which has nothing to do with Matlab... so I get your point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the header file 'ST_TopLevel_MWL.h' doesn't declare the variable for dll import using `__declspec(dllimport)`

An [msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa271769(v=vs.60).aspx) gives enough detail to explain it.  Here is an excerpt:

> "However, you must use __declspec(dllimport) in order to import variables used in a DLL."

The Matlab Simulink Embedded Coder 'ert_shrlib.tlc' target uses a .DEF file to expose the exported procedures and variables.  It uses straight up `extern ExtU_ST_TopLevel_MWL_T ST_TopLevel_MWL_U;` in the header file.  When the same header file that is used to compile the dll is also used for compilation on the importing side of things, the missing `__declspec(dllimport)` causes the built code to reference a phantom variable somewhere off in the weeds instead of the variable exported from the dll.  This leads to the Access Violation crash.

Editing the header file to replace "`extern`" with "`extern __declspec(dllimport)`" solves the problem.

Here is another useful link that explains the problem from Matlab Central:  [How do I call a DLL created from Simulink model in a Visual Studio application?](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/92917-how-do-i-call-a-dll-created-from-simulink-model-in-a-visual-studio-application)